# ASP Net Core decimal input with period turns into a whole number

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an input field which a price which is in the model a decimal.

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label">Price</label>
 <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

```cs
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Column(TypeName = "money")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

When I POST the input field with a comma the page returns a validation error,
when I POST with a period, the price is received as a whole number.
For example when I put the price as 7.00 I receive 700 in my controller.

[image]

Comment: check if you have comma or dot in decimals, and try to switch to opposite. this is related to current thread culture

Comment: I can only insert Periods as seperator but i still receive a whole number. 7.00 => 700

Comment: Could you show your controller action header for us pls?

Comment: I edited the post with the controller logic

Comment: what do you see if you do `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name` in controller

Comment: When i do that it shows: nl-NL

Comment: Thanks, but now I'd like to look at CreateMealViewModel  class.

Comment: @YegorAndrosov solved my problem, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nl-NL` culture uses comma as decimal separator. You can override current culture`s number format for each request with this code

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var currentThreadCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        currentThreadCulture.NumberFormat = NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentThreadCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentThreadCulture;

        await next();
    });
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP Net Core decimal input with period turns into a whole number:-

You just only need to convert the input value to decimal.

It can be achived by change the :

```
<input asp-for="Price" class="form-control"/>
```

to :

```
<input type="number" required name="Price" min="0" value="0" step=".01">
```